# Swift cast dictionary value as type

Tags: swift, dictionary, types, casting

I am looking for best way how can I make this code to one line:

```
if (dictionary["Amoumt"] is Double) {
    amount = dictionary["Amount"] as Double
} else {
    amount = NSString(string: dictionary["Amount"] as String).doubleValue
}
```

I have `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>` and I would like to parse values from it. I am using code like above but it's too many lines. I would like to make it to one line. Something like:

```
dictionary["Amount"].parseDouble()
```

There is no problem to create extension with this method:

```
func parseDouble() -> Double {
    if (self is Double) {
        return self as Double
    } else {
        return NSString(string:(self as String)).doubleValue
    }
}
```

But which type should I extend? Next could you help me with generic method? So I could call something like this:

```
dictionary["Amount"].parse(Double)
```

And is this good way how to do this or should I do it another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AnyObject` as is. Try:

```
var dictionary:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "foo": 4.21,    // NSNumber
    "bar": "42.5",  // NSString
    "baz": [1,2,3], // NSArray
]

let foo = dictionary["foo"]?.doubleValue ?? 0 // -> 4.21
let bar = dictionary["bar"]?.doubleValue ?? 0 // -> 42.5
let baz = dictionary["baz"]?.doubleValue ?? 0 // -> 0.0
```

This works because both `NSNumber` and `NSString` have `.doubleValue` property.
On the other hand, `NSArray` does not have that property, in this case it returns `nil`.

As described in [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_30):

> You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type. This includes Objective-C compatible methods marked with the `@objc` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this kind of extenison:

```
extension Dictionary{

    func parseDouble(key:Key) -> Double {

        let result = self[key]

        if (result is Double) {
            return result as Double
        } else {
            return NSString(string:(result as String)).doubleValue
        }
    }
}
```

And getting value for key by using this:

```
var doubleValue = dictionary.parseDouble("amount")
```

And a generic function

```
extension Dictionary{

    func parse<T>(key:Key) -> T? {

        let result = self[key]

        if (result is T) {
            return result as? T
        }

        return nil
    }
}

var doubleValue:Double? = myDistionary.parse("someKeyForDouble")

var stringValue:String? = myDistionary.parse("someKeyForString")
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to condense this is to use the nil coalescing operator and an optional double. This attempts to cast the value as a double. If it succeeds, it unwraps it, if it fails, it defaults to the second value, which comes from converting `dict[amount]' to a string and taking its double value.

```
var amount: Double? = nil

let dict: [String: AnyObject] = ["amount" : "1.2"]

amount = (dict["amount"] as? Double) ?? NSString(string: dict["amount"] as! String).doubleValue
```

And to make your function:

```
func getDouble(obj: AnyObject) -> Double {
    return (obj as? Double) ?? NSString(string: obj as! String).doubleValue
}
```

and you call it using `getDouble(dict["amount"])`. An extension for something like this is probably overkill in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted an extension, the best place to put it in theory would be `AnyObject` – because it is an `AnyObject` that you want to convert.

But `AnyObject` is actually a protocol, so you can't extend it.

I wouldn't recommend putting it as an extension to `Dictionary` – the coercing of a type into a double is not really anything to do with dictionaries.

So the best approach is to do it as a free function not as an extension:

```
func getDouble(obj: AnyObject?) -> Double {
    return (obj as? Double) ?? (obj as? NSString)?.doubleValue ?? 0
}
asDouble(dictionary["Amount"])
```

Note, this function is safe if you pass it a function that is neither a double nor a string.  Other solutions using `as` or `!` instead of `as?` will crash at runtime if you ever pass something else in.

You could argue it should return an optional, with nil if the value was not convertible to a double.  This is what `String.toInt()` does.  Unfortunately, the limitation of `NSString.doubleValue` is that it doesn't do this – it defaults to zero instead – so you can't combine these two approaches.